# How to fetch sum date from sql based on date if date is exist?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

In my app, I need to fetch `SUM(admin_amount)` with below condition.

**Table 1**

id, driver_id, admin_amount , trip_date

**Table 2**

id, driver_id, from_date, to_date, amount, created_date

In table2, Admin will get his commission amount from driver based on dates. For example, Driver have to pay Rs.1000 to admin for his ride commission between 2019-10-01 to 2019-10-10. So when driver comes to pay admin at that time I need to find total pending amount of driver to pay admin.

What I'm trying...

I'm trying to fetch last transaction date(created_date) from `table2` so I can get the date of last payment and based on that I can calculate `SUM(admin_change) till now`.

I can do this via two queries.

1) Fetch last date

```
SELECT * FROM  table2 
WHERE driver_id = 14 
ORDER BY created_date DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

2) If I got data then use the date in condition otherwise simple fetch SUM() of all data.

Can anyone help to achieve this in a single query?

**Try**

```
SELECT SUM(admin_amount) 
FROM table1 
WHERE driver_id = 33 
      AND trip_date >= (SELECT created_date 
                        from table2 
                        WHERE driver_id = 33 
                        ORDER by created_date DESC 
                        LIMIT 1);
```

This query works when any data exist but not works when table2  has no data of respective driver.

**Table1**

```
1, 33, 50, 2019-10-01
2, 33, 70, 2019-10-01
3, 33, 30, 2019-10-10
```

**Table2**

// If new driver then there is no transaction yet.

// If previous transaction is there then data will be like as below.

```
1, 33, 2019-10-01, 2019-10-10, 150, 2019-10-29
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks for edit and next time I'll take care to post a clear issue. :)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Can you please tell me which part confused you. I'll try to clear you.

Comment: For starters, there is no `admin_amount` column defined in either table1 or table2, while you are using it in your second query

Comment: Sorry it's type to admin_charge.

Comment: Update your question  add  a proper  (clear) data sample as tabular text  and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge Okay Just a minute. I'm adding it.

Comment: @scaisEdge question has been updated now.

Comment: based on your sample which is the expected  result  ??

Comment: @scaisEdge Simple sub of admin amount. E.x: 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand - When the subquery in the WHERE clause doesn't return anything (`NULL`), then you don't want to apply the condition `trip_date >= (...)`. You can use `COALESCE()` in this case to convert the returned `NULL` to a date, that is smaller than any possible value in `trip_date` (eg. `'1900-01-01'`). In this case the condition will be always evaluated to TRUE:

```
SELECT SUM(admin_amount) 
FROM table1 
WHERE driver_id = 33 
  AND trip_date >= COALESCE((
    SELECT created_date 
    from table2 
    WHERE driver_id = 33 
    ORDER by created_date DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  ), '1900-01-01');
```

To combine it with Madhur Bhaiya's deleted answer, you can use `MAX(created_date)` in the subquery.

```
SELECT SUM(admin_amount) 
FROM table1 
WHERE driver_id = 33 
  AND trip_date >= COALESCE((
    SELECT MAX(created_date)
    from table2 
    WHERE driver_id = 33 
  ), '1900-01-01');
```

This shouldn't make any diffrence - But I would prefer this, becuase it's shorter and also more portable (along different DBMS vendors).

Comment: Thanks for this query, I learn new from this. And when no data is there in table2 then also this works. I just test more cases and I'll get back to you. :)

Comment: @SachinShah this answer should be fine, or you can use `Max()` idea (alongwith `Coalesce()`) also from my (now deleted) answer. For good performance, you can define the following two indexes. On table2: Composite index `(driver_id, created_date)` - This will be a Covering index. On table1: Composite index `(driver_id, trip_date)`

Comment: I just replaced to_date with MAX(created_date) and it works for me. Thanks for your answer.